# Can exports property be set to object instead of function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, circular-dependency, browserify

I'm modularizing my client-side JavaScript code with Browserify.

In my "page" module, I'm trying to export an object with methods, like so:

```
// page.js

exports.picker = {
    init: function () { ... },
    getValue: function () { ... },
    // etc.
};
```

However, in another module, when I try to use one of these methods, I get a TypeError:

```
// other module

var page = require('./page');

// later...
page.picker.init(); // throws "TypeError: page.picker is undefined"
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is it maybe because I'm exporting an object instead of a function?

Comment: No, objects should be fine. Does it actually work if you use a function instead of the object literal?

Comment: The code works as given (after dropping the `...`s and trailing `,` in `page.js`).  Try writing a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Bergi No. Probably a n00b question, but does it matter if page.js also requires that other module (i.e. both modules require each other)? I have several such two-way dependencies in my modules. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is. You can usually avoid the issue by requiring one of them not from the module definition code, but directly inside a method that is only executed later. I'm not sure how node.js and how browserify do handle *circular dependencies* exactly, though.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, sounds like a plan. Another solution *could* be callbacks. (Currently I have module A invoke a method of module B, which then runs some code and after that invokes a method of module A in return. Instead, I could have A invoke a method of B and pass a callback via arguments. Then when B has run its code, it just invokes A's callback instead of having to invoke A's method directly.)

Comment: Are you also adding anything else to the exports? Anyway, try module.exports.pager